# How to restrict any function to the required number of days in pinescript

Tags: time, progress-bar, return-value, pine-script

I have created my Pivot plotting and now looking for resctricting it for the last few days only.

I am not able to restrict the same. can some one help me on the same.

Comment: What do you mean by restricting it for the last few days only? Do you want it to calculate only on the last n bars? Or do you want it to calculate on all bars and only show on the last n bars? Could you provide a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

In the plot function use show_last = x
Where x is the number of bars to show from the latest bar.

For example to plot the pivots on the last 10 bars use:

```
plot(series = pivots, title = "Pivots", show_last = 10)
```